# What does "storing a pointer to the data" in a blockchain mean?

Tags: relational-database, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've seen a lot of recommendations to store hashes of data and a pointer to the data where it is in storage rather than storing the data on the blockchain. I'm confused how you would store a pointer to the data on the chain. Say I have a medical record stored in the form of a table with various fields in a relational database somewhere. How do I "point" to this record and store that pointer in the blockchain? How would a user who has permission access it use this pointer to gain access to the data?

Thanks for any help with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are storing an `Id` to the record in storage.

Say, for example, you are adding a `User` to a transaction which is being added to the blockchain. You may not want to add all the information about a user to a blockchain. So you add the user to a database, then when you reference that user in the blockchain, you reference that user by some type of Id that is created for the database.

You would need to setup some other structure to allow all users to get the information, but that implementation is up to you and your application.

This is very helpful to keep lots of data off the blockchain, such as large images or videos, but also keep PII off the blockchain.